# I get the wrong latitude and longitude with phonegap geolocation

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

i'm using phone gap and I got the geolocation working like so:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        var options = { frequency: 3000 };
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);


    }
function onSuccess(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        long = position.coords.longitude;

        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + lat      + '<br />' +
        'Longitude: ' + long     + '<br />' +
        '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
}
```

But I get the wrong latitude and longitude when testing in xCode. Is that normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can go to the Debug -> Location option in the iOS simulator to change the GPS co-ordinates.

Comment: Yeah I can choose between different locations but not my own or I really need to put in the latitude and longitude, so I think I can't test the real coordinates in Xcode?